# How to rewrite /lib/web/magnifier/magnifier.js file in a custom module in magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2.3, overriding, lib, magnifier

Can we rewrite files in the `lib` folder?

If we can, I want to know how to rewrite `/lib/web/magnifier/magnifier.js` file in a custom module.

Comment: Have you tried rewrite the file in design folder? Do you only need to overwrite the file in your custom module?

Comment: I need to overwrite in custom module so that my modifications will reflect in all the themes.

Comment: Have you followed the steps posted in below answer by sandip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it below in the custom module. This is a working example.

1. Create `requirejs-config.js` in `app/code/Custom/Pro/view/frontend directory` if not exists.

`var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            "magnifier/magnifier": "Custom_Pro/js/magnifier/magnifier"
        }
    },
    shim:{
        "Custom_Pro/magnifier/magnifier":["jquery"]
    }
};`

2. Create file named `magnifier.js` in `app/code/Custom/Pro/view/frontend/web/js/magnifier` directory.
   Copy original `magnifier.js` file from `lib/web/magnifier/magnifier.js` and paste it in `app/code/Custom/Pro/view/frontend/web/js/magnifier` directory.
3. Make the required changes in the `magnifier.js` located in the `app/code/Custom/Pro/view/frontend/web/js/magnifier/magnifier.js`
4. Execute below command in order to effect at frontend
   `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
   `php bin/magento s:s:d -f -s standard`

Note: 
1. Change your custom module from `Custom/Pro`.
2. To confirm check below file calling on the frontend.
`www.example.com/static/versionXXXXXX/frontend/Vendor/Theme/en_US/requirejs-config.js`

For More Info. **Refer Replace a default JS component** section available at the below URL.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html

Comment: Accepting this solution as the answer as it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite in design folder,

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/magnifier/magnifier.js
```