# Magento2: Override issue for lib/web/jquery.js

Tags: magento2, overrides, jquery, lib

I am trying to override below file in my custom theme.

> lib/web/jquery.js

Seems it been override. But It stop other jquery from working.

[image]

Due to this a lot of console error arise.

[image]

Here is my code

> app/design/frontend/custom/theme/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'jquery':'js/custom-jquery'
        }
    }
};
```

I have placed my override file here:

> app/design/frontend/custom/theme/web/js/custom-jquery.js

Can anyone please suggest how to override **lib/web/jquery.js** properly.

Comment: Look at this answer - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/303519/34579  - Maybe `shim`  is missing for the main jquery in `app/design/frontend/custom/theme/requirejs-config.js`. Why do you want to override the main `jquery.js`?

Comment: Due to this issue: https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/issues/445  I have to override this file